# How to debug an iframe/webview in electron framework

Tags: iframe, electron

[image]I have webview/iFrame inside electron framework. I want to debug the code inside the iFrame.

I launch electron app with debugger windowas shown in the picture.

I want to debug the content that gets loaded.

Answer (score 1):

In your renderer script, get the webview and open its devtools. You're opening the devtools of the renderer that contains the webview.

```
document.querySelector("webview").openDevTools();
```

[Source](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag#webviewopendevtools)

Comment: Thanks @pushkin, works also in Insomnia Rest when you try and debug the html response.